# Where in the Nexus docs is it documented that "LATEST" redirects to the latest version?

Tags: nexus

So it seems that giving Nexus a version of "LATEST" will tell it to redirect to latest version of the specified build product.

Where in the docs is this actually documented?

Comment: At one point it was documented as part of the REST API, but I can't find a current working link (thus a comment and not an answer)

Comment: Appreciate the info, though; the REST API docs seem to have vanished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAQ contains detailed explanation:
https://docs.sonatype.com/display/SPRTNXOSS/Nexus+FAQ#NexusFAQ-Q.HowcanIretrieveasnapshotifIdon%27tknowtheexactfilename%3F

But also the REST API doco (bundled with every Nexus instance) contains it too. Just login as Admin, go to Administration, Plugin Console, select Core Documentation plugin in grid, and client on the "Core API" link on lower panel.